# C# Regex Replace How to append text to end of each line(C#)

Tags: c#, string

I have searched the site for this simple problem but cant find an answer.

I have a multiline string . I want to add a constant string to end of each line.
I am using Regex.Replace but facing problems. I tried to replace as the following.

```
   Pattern             Replace With
-------------------------------------------
    $                   Text
    ($)                 Text$1
    \n                  Text
    \n                  Text\n
    (\n)                Text$1
```

But none of these work. In all the cases the multiple lines are joined into a single line.
How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: I don't understand the table at all. What are you trying to depict?

Comment: How do you plan to map one of the patterns to *two* different replacements? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I took the table as the pattern (regex) he tried to match the end of line with and the replacement as what he tried to replace the end of the line with (including the "Text" he wanted to append)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

`string newString = oldString.Replace("\r\n", "Text\r\n");`

replace Text with the string you want to append to the end of each line

Comment: I was using Text from a Windows forms TextBox and displaying the result in the textbox.The texbox somehow does not display this correctly- bu the string gets replaced correctly.

Comment: From one text box to another it would be:

newTB.Text = oldTb.Text.Replace("\r\n", "Text\r\n");

Glad I could be of help :o)